# Метает или мечет?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В выражении метать громы и молнии? Мне говорят, что мечут только икру, а все остальное метают. Это правда?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: У меня  вопрос: Метать  бисер перед свиньями. 
Это на усмотрение метающего или мечущего ? 

Comment: Слова из Нагорной проповеди Иисуса: «Не давайте святыни псам и не мечите бисера вашего перед свиньями..." С точки зрения церковников: бисер (жемчуга) — драгоценные знания христианского учения; свиньи — люди с низменными страстями; метать - как мечет икру рыба.



Answer (score 4):

Нет, это не правда. Метают в литературном языке только шов крупными стежками, да петли при вязании, да спортивные снаряды иногда. Всё остальное мечут в том числе и громы с молниями.

См. [Ушаков](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/859202), [грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EC%E5%F2%E0%F2%FC&all=x)

Answer (score 4):

**Метать**(ся)**1** - прошивать крупными стежками. Метаю, метает(ся), метают(ся). Пов. МЕТАЙ. Прич. МЕТАЮЩИЙ, МЕТАВШИЙ. Деепр. МЕТАЯ. 
**Метать2** - бросать, кидать, метать икру. Мечу, мечет, мечут. Пов. МЕЧИ(ТЕ). Прич. МЕЧУЩИЙ, МЕТАВШИЙ. Деепр. МЕЧА. 
***Из "Нового орфоэпического словаря русского языка" Т.Ф. Ивановой.***

Answer (score 3):

Спортивные снаряды метают **всегда**. Увы, тут уважаемый автор или ошибается, или не просто не рассматривает спортивную терминологию, считая её жаргоном. Найдите хоть одно подходящее упоминание в спортивных изданиях в сочетании с "мечут" - и я возьму свои слова обратно.

*метать, метаю, метаешь; пов. метай(прошивать крупными стежками); метает шов; метает петли*

*метать, метаю, метаешь; пов. метай(спорт.); метает гранату, копьё, диск*

*метать, мечу, мечешь; пов. мечи(бросать, кидать в прямом и перен. знач.; производить потомство); мечет стог; мечет гневные взоры; мечет громы и молнии; рыба мечет икру/*

Русское словесное ударение.Словарь нарицательных имён.
Автор М. В. Зарва.

Так что громы и молнии - мечут. Тут бесспорно уже потому, что идиома весьма старая, сохранившая исходную форму, не испорченную спортивной терминологией.

В отношении других метательных снарядов (стрелы, например, или ядра), которые по мнению большинства, если не всех, авторов (включая Иванову), тоже мечут - ничего не могу сказать наверняка, но подозреваю, что сейчас и их тоже метают. Я просто не вижу принципиальной разницы в процессе метания со спортивными и военными целями, особенно когда дело касается, например, гранат.

Короче, я думаю, что метать="бросать" в прямом смысле все более приобретает форму "метает", а в переносном остается "мечет". Таким образом позиция вашего оппонента не лишена смысла (вопреки, видимо, мнению предыдыших отвечавших) но она на громы и молнии не распространяется.

Comment: Кстати, у меня есть словарь трудностей словоупотребления 1974-ого года, и там именно, что указано про спортивное употребление "метает", и рекомендацию не использовать такой вариант в общем языке. С тех пор, по-моему, только популярнее стало.