# Как правильно писать слово, которое обозначает движение?

Tags: выбор-слов

Какое из слов правильно в значении движения: мечутся или метаются? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры употребления обоих слов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Слишком много для комментария к предыдущему ответу.) Этот ответ по сути своей совпадает с предыдущим, но содержит дополнительную информацию, которая может быть интересна.

Д.Э. Розенталь в учебнике для вузов "Практическая стилистика русского языка" говорит следующее:

> *Метать — мечет* имеет значение «разбрасывать, направлять» (*мечет гневные взоры, мечет гром и молнии*, также: *мечет икру*), в том же
>   значении «бросать» в спортивном обиходе употребляется форма *метает*
>   (**метает копье**); омонимический глагол метать в значении «прошивать
>   стежками, обшивать петли» имеет форму *метает* (**метает шов**). В паре
>   *метается — мечется* первая форма имеет устарелый или разговорный
>   характер; ср.: *Он бросается с одра своего, **метается** по земле* (Фонв.)
>   — *Она **мечется**, как дикий зверь* (Л. Андр.).

P.S. Замечу, что автоматическая проверка орфографии не согласилась в этом ответе с формами *метает, метается*.

Answer (score 3):

В настоящее время согласно словарю нормированными считаются только формы ***мечется, мечутся,*** а формы ***метаются, метается*** устарели, в текстах практически не используются. https://slovar.cc/rus/zaliznyak/1504979.html

Из словаря:

МЕТАТЬСЯ, **мечусь, мечешься;** нсв. 1. Быстро и беспорядочно устремляться то в одну, то в другую сторону. Чайки стонут перед бурей, стонут, мечутся над морем (Горький). 2. Беспокойно и беспорядочно двигаться, ворочаться, ёрзать. М. во сне. Больной мечется в бреду. 3. Находиться в состоянии смятения, растерянности.  М. в ожидании чего-л.

Неприкрытая хлопает дверь, Под деревьями **мечутся** тени. [Александр Городницкий.(2015)]

Полчища зануд-политологов **мечутся** от одной модели к другой и только вносят сумятицу. [Александр Невзоров.  // «Однако», 2009]

Из поющего птицами сада пестреют колонки, блестят изразцы; антилопа **метается** в клетке испуганным рогом: [Андрей Белый. Африканский дневник (1922)]

Рыба **мечется,** сопротивляясь, а мне важно не дать леске слабину. [Р. Б. Ахмедов. Промельки (2011) // «Бельские Просторы», ]

Я снова высунулся наружу и в свете молний увидел, как **мечется** по краю поля лохматое призрачное пятно. [Юрий Коваль. (1974)]

Он не понимает, в чем дело, и просто **мечется** по своей пещере от страха. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]

Comment: Немного странно, что в словаре А.Зализняка нет формы "метаются, метается". Ведь эти слова вполне употребимы, хотя и в других значениях: на соревнованиях _нож метается в мишень_, в шитье _петля метается_ (последнее отмечено в словаре Лопатина). (Это не возражение к ответу.)

Comment: В ваших примерах это пассивный залог от глагола "метать", но в парадигме для "метать"  этих форм тоже нет. Может быть, пассивный залог не отражается в парадигме.

Answer (score 2):

**Подобный вопрос уже обсуждался:** [Метает или мечет?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19424/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82)

А. **Комментарий**

В русском языке есть **ряд глаголов,** где делается выбор между двумя формами (с усеченным и неусеченным глагольным суффиксом): метает и мечет, двигает и движет, колышет и колыхает, блистает и блещет, брызгает и брызжет, капает и каплет.

**Различаются эти формы по стилю и по смыслу.** Обычное глагол с неусеченным суффиксом относят к разговорному стилю. **А вот различение по смыслу – вопрос интересный,** и решать его желательно в общем виде, чтобы избежать частных (для каждого глагола) и, возможно, не всегда верных выводов.

Возьмем, к примеру, глагол ***капать***. Дождь капает и каплет, а  вот лекарство только капают. Устами движет бог (поэт.), а человек двигает пальцами. Фонтан брызжет, а цветы брызгают водой.

Из этих сравнений можно сделать **вывод**: для самодостаточного (а также активного, интенсивного или непрерывного) действия больше подходит **усеченная форма** (хотя могут использоваться обе), а **неусеченная форма** обычно требует наличия инструментального объекта, также эта форма в большей степени пассивная или имеет единичный харктер действия.

**Б. Интересный пример**:http://mydocx.ru/1-6243.html

Выясните смысловые и стилистические оттенки глагольных форм.

Время движется вперед. – Каждый раз казалось, что дело не двигается.

Ты капаешь себе на колени. – Над нами не каплет.

Ветер **мечет** по поляне груды пожелтевших листьев. – Здесь копья **метает** дикарь краснолицый.

Красивой плеткой он махает. – Она мне тихо машет: подойдите.

Эти хулиганы через забор на прохожих брызгают. – Молодость брызжет из голубых радостных глаз.

**В. Мечет или метает?**

Рыба  **мечет икру** (внутренний объект, непрерывное и активное действие), спортсмен **метает копьё** (внешний объект, единичное действие). Но **мечет ножи** (один за другим).

**Метает петли** – это уже другое (переносное) значение глагола.

Но сейчас форма ***мечет*** вытесняет (или старается вытеснить) форму ***метает***:

**Метает (7 примеров)**

Кто быстрее бегает, выше прыгает или дальше **метает** диск ― узнать достаточно просто.  «Наука и жизнь», 2009.

Вторая равнодушно **метает** на прилавок тарелки с пельменями. [Андрей Макаревич. Дом (2001)]

Снять Пыжова с грузовика! Пусть стога **метает** вместе с другими.  [А. И. Мусатов. Зелёный шум (1963)]

Звоню Юре, он рвет и **метает**. Вот бедлам… [Александр Болдырев. Осадная запись (блокадный дневник) (1941-1948)

**Мечет (300 примеров).**

Нет, мне не хотелось, чтоб товарищ мой был таким дураком, который **мечет** ножи в деревья. [Юрий Коваль. Ножевик (1990)]

Начальство каждый день в плохом настроении, **рвет и мечет**...

Кузьмич верит в приметы и **стога мечет** в одних полотняных подштанниках и такой же рубахе. [Алексей Иванов. (1982)]