# Бисер - мечут или метают? А копье, гранату?

Tags: грамматика

Когда-то я с этим вопросом разбирался.
Но вот что-то сомнения одолели.

Если кратко, мечут - икру и и вообще все, что не является единичным объектом (громы и молнии), все остальное - метают (копье, например)
Но отдельные исключения возможны - петли на швейном производстве, тут немного другое значение, потому метают или обметывают.

Интересно, что из всех "грамотных" словарей, только Зарва признаёт в явном виде "метаю копьё". Лопатин и Кузнецов, вроде как за "мечу". 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

UPD
Рещил добавить. После выяснения вопроса с бисером (а он сам по себе и не столь сложный), суть вопроса в том, верно ли разделение по принципу множественности объекта метания (икра, потомство, громы и молнии, взгляды), исключая петли (так как єто другое значение вообще), против единственности (копье, граната). Похоже, что именно так. Правда смущает, что "метают" все на дальность или точность, а вот у "мечут" такого значения не просматривается. Но это не сильно противоречит предложенному разделению на множестенное-единственное.

*Другой же подход - восстановить исходное значение порождающих парадигмы инфинитивов "мести" и "метать". При таком подходе неоднозначность при выборе формы придется связать именно с наличием двух порождающих инфинитивов. Но тут я что-то теряюсь, очень уж странное месиво из форм получатся. Я мечу, метаю, мету, выметаю, вымечу, вымету, отметаю, отмету, отмеч**у**... 
А еще путается созвучное "метить" - с совершенно другим историческим корневым морфом...*

*Не залезая в дебри исторической грамматики не разобраться в исходных парадигмах, а без этого и делать на этом пути тут нечего.*

Comment: Вопрос обсуждался  на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19424/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: @Jasmin Нет, там про бисер вообще нет, а остальное - поверхностно и недостоверно.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. ИМХО он демонстрирует особенность русского языка: не на всё можно найти простое правило, а если правило находится - оно нам не нравится :)

Comment: @ddbug  просто надо различать искусственно придуманные правила-запоминалки (типа орфограмок) и правила, которые можно восстановить исходя из исторической грамматики. Вот попытка свести разделение между правильными формами по линии "метаю петли" - "мечу все остальное" явно искусственна. Такие "правила" не могут не содержать в себе потенциальных исключений.

Comment: Так и я же про что. Вы найдёте или восстановите правила на базе неких источников или реконструкции. При этом оказывается что устоявшиеся уже в языке формы не соответствуют этим правилам. И что делать?

Comment: @ddbug *При этом оказывается что устоявшиеся уже в языке формы не соответствуют этим правилам. И что делать?* Понятия не имею. Я так вопрос не ставлю. Я возражаю лишь тем, кто ищет (и находит) какие-то правила там, где их нет и быть не может. А ваш случай - это, видимо, из области "Тем хуже для фактов". Здесь, видимо, смешение двух значений слова "правило" - руководство к действию (єто то, что ві говорите) и некая ємпирическая или теоретическая закономернность (єто то, о чем я)., Эта закономерность позволяет что-то понять, но сама по себе никаким наставлением или инструкцией не является.

Comment: Поэтому и делать с ней ничего не надо.

Comment: Кстати, и с блог(?)гером та же петрушка. Вы как будто нашли весомые аргументы - но народ не согласен.

Comment: @ddbug не уже очень помню, что там было с блогером и какая с связь с нынешней темой... Но если безотносительно ко всему этому, то ситуация, когда самые убедительные аргументы не находят отклика вполне мне знакома. Тут две причины, во-первых, спорящие (назовем так) по разному видят предмет спора, это не самое страшное, можно договориться. А вот во-вторых, это принципиальное неприятие методологии спора, основанного на применении чистых силлогизмов. Вот это беда просто.

Comment: В особо тяжелых случаях такой спор глухого со слепым превращается в обмен аргументами ниачем, когда как минимум одна сторона (а чаще - обе) начинает городить аргументы, которые просто не относятся к предмету спора. Тут я просто бессилен - и очень завидую своим бывшим коллегам-математикам, которые остались в специальности. Там подобный спор ниачем невозможен в принципе, поскольку выработан общий единый для всех подход, основанный на силлогизмах тира "А влечет Б"...   Не имею возможности тут эту тему развивать, но постоянно с подобным сталкиваюсь

Answer (score 1):

***Метать*** ― многозначный глагол: (1)с силой бросать; (2) накидывая, складывать,  (3)производить потомство.

Если не рассматривать значение (2), то выбор делается для форм со значением (1) и (2): **метает или мечет.**

Рыба **мечет** икру (из себя) ― это однозначно. Копье/гранату бросают, то есть **метают**.

Но форма  ***мечет*** употребляется  в различных случаях (303 примера в Нацкорпусе), и часто к рыбе эти формы не относятся.
 http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%E5%F7%E5%F2

Значит, это **переносное значение**. Всё, что **похоже на метание икры, всё, делается  с большой скоростью/интенсивностью и поэтому  напоминает этот процесс,** ― всё это обозначают формой ***мечет***: мечет рюмки в себя, мечет тарелки на стол, мечет громы и молнии, рвёт и мечет, мечет бисер, дротик, стрелы, слова.

Спортсмен ***метает (бросает)*** копьё (разовое движение). Враги валят на нас со стен камни, льют кипяток, расплавленную смолу, ***мечут копья (= быстро бросают одно за одним),*** осыпают стрелами. [В. В. Вересаев. Воспоминания (1925-1935)]

**Примеры:**

Но лишь проблеснет заря и брызнут искры рассвета, зимушка без оглядки пускается в бегство ― вдогонку ей несутся птичьи щебеты, горланят петухи, и **солнце мечет блещущие копья.** [Артем Веселый. Россия, кровью умытая (1924-1932)]

Шарит казак руками по земле вокруг себя ― ищет камней, находит и **мечет их в реку.** [Максим Горький. Исповедь (1908)]

**О бисере:**

В современную речь выражение пришло из церковно-славянского текста Библии. В Евангелии от Матфея (гл. 7, ст. 6) приведены слова из Нагорной проповеди Иисуса Христа: «Не давайте святыни псам и **не бросайте жемчуга вашего** перед свиньями, чтобы они не попрали его ногами своими и, обратившись, не растерзали вас». В народе евангельская цитата преобразовалась в выражение «метать бисер перед свиньями» (на Руси жемчуг называли бисером) и стала крылатой. http://www.aif.ru/dontknows/eternal/otkuda_poshlo_vyrazhenie_metat_biser_pered_svinyami

Форма ***мечет*** связана **с выражением сильных эмоций** и, соответственно, обозначает **интенсивность и непрерывность действия**:

(1)  **Не бросайте жемчуга вашего** ― не говорите с ними о святынях, не тратьте на них свои сильные и яркие чувства,  не пытайтесь убедить их в чем-то своим красноречием.

(2) **Рвет и мечет** ― в Сети есть объяснение фразеологизма (за достоверность не ручаюсь). Игрок в состоянии крайнего возбуждения рвет колоду (распечатывает ее) и мечет (бросает) карты на стол. http://fb.ru/article/251464/rvet-i-mechet-smyisl-pogovorki-istoriya-i-primeryi-upotrebleniya

(3) **Мечет громы и молнии** ―  в воображении древних  боги сидели на облаках и гневно метали оттуда свои «молнии» и «громы»

Comment: *(1)с силой бросать; (2) накидывая, складывать, (3)производить потомство.* - У Кузнецова значений аж восемь. И не очевидно, что все они сводятся к эти трем. Группировка у него тоже другая: "метаю" (петли), и семь других значений - "мечу". Это сомнительно, но считать пять или шесть приводимых им значений (никакого отношения ни к рыбе, ни к рождению потомства вообще не имеющих)  "переносными"  - еще более сомнительно. Тут нужен какой-то более продуманный, что ли, подход.

Comment: Колебание наблюдается в одном значении: бросать - бросает и метать - метает/мечет, его и надо прежде всего анализировать. И  желательно учитывать не только мнения лингвистов из словарей, но и практику использования слова, то есть то, что называют usus (общепринятое носителями   употребление яз. единиц). Без учета практики задачу не решить. К примеру, возьмем  пару "метает копьё и мечут копья". Разница значений чувствуется, она реальна в настоящее время. А что скажут словари и лингвисты? Это норма, это нет, это современно,  это устарело и т.д. В Сети эту пару постоянно обсуждают, а где ответ?

Comment: *Колебание наблюдается в одном значении: бросать - бросает и метать - метает/мечет, его и надо прежде всего анализировать.* - нет. Не только там - и не только его надо анализировать, если хочется иметь общее понимание - и общее правило.

Comment: *"метает копьё и мечут копья"* - разница только в том, что второй вариант может использовать только совершенно не понимающий сути "метания" человек. Две копья сразу один человек метнуть не может. А если и сможет, тогда это будет не метание, а что-то другое. Ну вот именно то, что рыбы делают. Отсюда, кстати, и сомнения насчет "Громов и молний". Но тут, правда, есть и такое понимание, что Зевс это делает именно одновременно (одноактово), посему "мечет"  оправдано.

Comment: Спортсмен (сейчас) метает копье, спортсмены (сейчас) метают копья, но воины в разгаре битвы мечут копья (копья летят одно за другим, множество копий). Это не соревнование с судьями, это настоящее сражение, и надо различать эти значения. А различают ли их словари?

Comment: *но воины в разгаре битвы мечут копья*  - А один воин тоже "мечет"? мне это кажется совершенно диким. Хотя, если автор здесь вкладывал тот смысл, что "мечут" копья беспорядочно, бесцельно, то я его могу понять. Правда, для этого надо рассматривать все войско как единый организм... "Войско мечет" (бессмысленно и беспощадно). Хотя войска все равно получается "метают.". Ладно, это уже все больше превращается в мало аргументированный спор о вкусах.

Comment: Хорошо, в качестве последнего замечания, закрывающего тему.  Один воин, конечно, ничего не мечет,  а воины мечут копья    в собирательном значении. Детали не важны, но важен общий эффект.